How to determine $\alpha$ of a shift operator $W_{\alpha}$ in $l^2$?
Problem: For each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, operator $W_\alpha\in B(l^2)$ is def as follows:
$$(W_\alpha a)_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & n=1 , \\[6pt]
(\frac{n}{n-1})^{\alpha}a_{n-1} & n\geq 2.
\end{array}
\right.$$
Determine the value of $\alpha$ for which the range $R(I-W_\alpha)$ is dense in $l^2$.
My prompt: Since we can check that for $n\geq2$ , $(W_\alpha^* a)_n=(\frac{n+1}{n})^{\alpha}a_{n+1}$, then consider $$\overline{R(I-W_\alpha)}=l^2 \iff R(I-W_\alpha)^{\perp}=Ker(I-W_\alpha)^*=Ker(I-W_\alpha^*)=\{0\}$$
then we can get a value of $\alpha$. Meanwhile for $W_{\alpha}\in B(l^2)$ we can calculate the range of $\alpha.$
My question: I'd like to know if the above approach is feasible, and regarding the case where $W_\alpha$ is a bounded operator in $l^2$, I’m not sure how to determine the range of $\alpha$. Also are there any cases that determine the value of $\alpha$ that haven't been considered?

Is $R$ just the shift operator? Also, you are talking about $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, right?

The problem can be generalized as follows. Let $m_n$ be a positive and bounded sequence.  Define the operator
$$(Wa)_n= \begin{cases}0 & n=1\\
m_{n-1}a_{n-1} &n\ge 2\end{cases}$$ The range $R(I-W)$ is dense iff $\ker (I-W^*)=\{0\}.$
We have
$W=SM,$ where
$$(M a)_n=m_na_n\quad (Sa)_n=\begin{cases}0 & n=1\\
a_{n-1} &n\ge 2\end{cases}$$
Thus $W^*=M S^*$ and
$$(W^*a)_n = m_{n+1}a_{n+1}$$ We have $W_\alpha^*a=a$ iff $$ m_{k+1}a_{k+1}=a_k,\quad k\ge 1$$ If $a\neq 0,$ then $a_1\neq 0.$ We have
$$a_{k+1}=m_k^{-1} a_k$$
which implies
$$a_{n}=(m_{1}m_2\ldots m_{n-1})^{-1}a_1 $$ Then $a\in \ell^2$ iff
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (m_{1}m_2\ldots m_{n-1})^{-2}<\infty$$ For $m_n=\left  ({n+1\over n}\right )^\alpha $ we get
$$(m_1m_2\ldots m_{n-1})^{-2}=n^{-2\alpha} $$ Thus $\ker(I-W_\alpha)=\{0\} $ iff $\alpha\le {1\over 2}.$

Thanks for your reply, but the convergence range of the last step series maybe should be α＞1/2.

The kernel is trivial when the series is divergent, i.e. $\alpha\le 1/2.$

I got it，thanks！
